# How to resize column width in RStudio source pane?

Tags: rstudio, viewer

Can anyone tell me how to resize a column in the source pane of RStudio? I tried renaming the second column from "n" to "Total number" but it just wraps the header text.

[Screen grab of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf8XN.png)

Edit: Earlier screen grab did not, in fact, show the problem. This does.
[image: Screen with the numbers truncated.]

Comment: AFAIK you can't really adjust the column widths in the Viewer. In this case, why do you want to resize it? It looks like none of your numbers is truncated... Maybe you could rename it `Total_number`?

Comment: Just added a screen grab showing the numbers truncated.I think I know what happened as I was able to replicate it. I use Cmd+ on the Mac to zoom in and out and looks like I had zoomed in to look at something, which action untruncated the numbers, but I went on with screen grab not noticing what had happened. I spent some time figuring out how to widen the column, gave up and took it to a spreadsheet. I guess zooming in is a work-around, at least for small tables.

Comment: Ok. I can't reproduce it, on my machine everything is displayed correctly.